# Integrating Firebase deployment and github repo with selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I have been writing UI tests with Selenium for my friend's web app that's hosted on Google's Firebase.

I was wondering if there's any way to integrate my existing test repository (maven project on github repo) into Continuous Integration pipeline with deployment that he does in Firebase?

Would it be possible to do e.g. in GitLab?

Comment: you can make the deployment happen through Jenkins and add a step to run the selenium test once the deployment is completed it completed. You need to use maven and maven surefire plugin to run tests in ci/cd